# Overlapping numerical values on Cook's distance plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I want to identify a couple of points with high leverage on the plot below, but unfortunately, their row number is illegible, because there must be a couple of such points, and their id is printed out one on top of the other. They are all the way to the right of the plot:

[image]

How can the print out of these labels on the plot be resized and spread out so that they can be legible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find the cooks distance is the built in function:

```
LM = lm(speed ~ dist, cars)
cooks.distance(LM)
```

You can pick out whatever values you want:

```
> which(cooks.distance(LM) > 0.05)
 1  2 23 35 39 49 
 1  2 23 35 39 49
```

Comment: So in my case I get `max(cooks.distance(fit))  [1] 0.03157539`. How do I go back and identify the corresponding row in the original data.frame?

Comment: `match(max(cooks.distance(fit)), cooks.distance(fit))
[1] 787`